# Show value based on dropdown

Tags: php, widgets

I am trying to create a short code with a form I have the form displaying ok but I need to be able to pull the price information from sql table as well and show it in a label.

How can i do that using the following code.

```
<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: WordPress ShortCode
* Description: Fules Plugin.
* Version: 1.0

*/

// Example 1 : WP Shortcode to display form on any page or post.
function form_creation(){

   global $wpdb;
?>
<form>

Liters:<select>
<?php
     $sql = 'SELECT liters FROM wp_tfp';
     $liters = $wpdb->get_col($sql);

if( $liters ) { 
  foreach( $liters as $liter ) { 
        echo '<option value="' . $liter . '">' . $liter . '</option>';
  }
}
?> 
</select>
Price: <input type="text" name="price"><br>

</form>
<?php
}
add_shortcode('test', 'form_creation');
?>
```

Comment: What is the structure of the `wp_tfp` table?  Is the price already in that table?  What is the `$liter`; is that not the price?

Comment: Please edit your questions with update and progress, rather than asking essentially same question multiple times.